# SqlContainer Filter case sensitive Vaadin

Tags: mysql, macos, vaadin, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I am new to Vaadin and have been trying to use the SqlContainer. I have managed to get mysql database connection working. Here is the connection and the container code:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.SQLContainer;
import com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.connection.JDBCConnectionPool;
import com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.connection.SimpleJDBCConnectionPool;
import com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.TableQuery;
import com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.generator.filter.QueryBuilder;
import com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.generator.filter.StringDecorator;

public class DatabaseHelper implements Serializable {
    private JDBCConnectionPool connectionPool = null;
    private SQLContainer credentialContainer= null;

    public DatabaseHelper() {
        initConnectionPool();
    }

    private void initConnectionPool() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connectionPool = new SimpleJDBCConnectionPool(
                    "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vaadin", "root", "mysqlpass",
                    2, 10);
            initContainers();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void initContainers() {
        try {
            /* TableQuery and SQLContainer for personaddress -table */
            QueryBuilder.setStringDecorator(new StringDecorator("`","`"));
            TableQuery q1 = new TableQuery("credentials", connectionPool);
            q1.setVersionColumn("version");
            credentialContainer= new SQLContainer(q1);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public SQLContainer getcredentialContainer(){
        return credentialContainer;
    }

}
```

Then I have used filters on the container as such:

```
credentialcontainer.removeAllContainerFilters();
credentialcontainer.addContainerFilter("username", username.getValue(), false, true);
```

However, the problem is that I have noticed that the filter is ignoring case even when I am setting it to ignoreCase parameter to false.

Anyone knows if this is a bug or if I am doing something wrong?
Note: I am using OS X and running a local MYSQL server.

Comment: This is now resolved!

The problem was not with Vaadin SqlContainer. The I didn't realise that because of the default collate on MYSQL the comparisons are case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now resolved! The problem was not with Vaadin SqlContainer. The I didn't realise that because of the default collate on MYSQL the comparisons are case-insensitive.